# How to plot a subset of data in Stata?

Tags: plot, regression, subset, stata

How can I write the code to do the following:

`scatter salaries female || lfit part98 female if group1==1`

I'm trying to plot `salaries` against `female` and include the best linear regression fit, but only from the observations in `group1`. (There are 3 groups in the dataset.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want something like:

```
clear all
set more off

sysuse auto

twoway scatter mpg weight || lfit mpg weight || if foreign
```

or equivalently

```
twoway (scatter mpg weight) (lfit mpg weight) if foreign
```

Read the complete `help twoway` for details.

Answer (score 0):

What also may be helpful as you are learning these new graphing commands (I know it was for me) is to use the menu options at the top of Stata. Go to Graphics > Twoway graph (scatter, line, etc.).  Once you play around with these, the code shows up in the command line and is a very helpful way to learn the syntax so you can code faster.